# Error on retrieving double data from DataSnapshot

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```
void retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId, BuildContext context)
{
  newRequestsRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((value) => (DataSnapshot dataSnapShot)
  {
    if(dataSnapShot.value != null)
    {
      assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio("sounds/alert.mp3"));
      assetsAudioPlayer.play();

      double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());   //  ['pickup']
      double pickUpLocationLng = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['longitude'].toString()); //['pickup']
      String pickUpAddress = dataSnapShot.value['pickup_address'].toString();

      double dropOffLocationLat = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['dropoff']['latitude'].toString());
      double dropOffLocationLng = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['dropoff']['longitude'].toString());
      String dropOffAddress = dataSnapShot.value['dropoff_address'].toString();

      String paymentMethod = dataSnapShot.value['payment_method'].toString();

      String rider_name = dataSnapShot.value["rider_name"];
      String rider_phone = dataSnapShot.value["rider_phone"];

      RideDetails rideDetails = RideDetails(pickup_address: '', dropoff_address: '');
      rideDetails.ride_request_id = rideRequestId;
      rideDetails.pickup_address = pickUpAddress;
      rideDetails.dropoff_address = dropOffAddress;
      rideDetails.pickup = LatLng(pickUpLocationLat, pickUpLocationLng);
      rideDetails.dropoff = LatLng(dropOffLocationLat, dropOffLocationLng);
      rideDetails.payment_method = paymentMethod;
      rideDetails.rider_name = rider_name;
      rideDetails.rider_phone = rider_phone;

      print("Information :: ");
      print(rideDetails.pickup_address);
      print(rideDetails.dropoff_address);

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => NotificationDialog(rideDetails: rideDetails,),
      );
    }
  });
```

The main porpuse of this codeset is to retrieve the data from the DataSnapShot(from firebase real time database) and distribute it in such a way that will be able to be used in different methods.

The problem i face is focused on that part of the code:

```
double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString()); 
double pickUpLocationLng = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['longitude'].toString());
```

1. Tried to retrieve is as individual with dataSnapShot.child -> Didn't worked.
2. Tried to retrieve is as individual with dataSnapShot.child -> Didn't worked.
3. Tried to retrieve is with separate class  -> Didn't worked.
4. Tried to insert null check  -> Didn't worked.
5. Tried to retrieve is separate and compine it in a list  -> Didn't worked.

In all of the above i get the same error :

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `snapshot.value` may be `null`. You might be testing for `null`, but in between that check and when you access the value there's a theoretical chance that it becomes `null` again.

The solution is to assign `snapshot.value` to a local variable and then use that:

```
newRequestsRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((value) => (DataSnapshot dataSnapShot)
{
  if(dataSnapShot.value != null)
  {
    var value = dataSnapShot.value!; // 

    assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio("sounds/alert.mp3"));
    assetsAudioPlayer.play();
                                              
    double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());   //  ['pickup']
    ...
```